# How to specify DataTemplate for object

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, converters, datatemplate

I have following code:

```
public class FieldViewerSelector : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public DataTemplate PercentTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate FileSizeTemplate { get; set; }

    #region IValueConverter Members
    //....
    #endregion
}

<commonConverters:FieldValueConverter x:Key="FieldValueConverter" />
<commonConverters:PercentValueConverter x:Key="PercentValueConverter" />
<commonConverters:FileSizeValueConverter x:Key="FileSizeValueConverter" />

<commonConverters:FieldViewerSelector x:Key="FieldViewerSelector">

    <commonConverters:FieldViewerSelector.FileSizeTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--DataTemplate almost the same-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </commonConverters:FieldViewerSelector.FileSizeTemplate>

    <commonConverters:PercentValueConverter>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--DataTemplate almost the same-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </commonConverters:PercentValueConverter>

</commonConverters:FieldViewerSelector>


<DataTemplate x:Key="template">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource LeftColumn}" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}"/>

        <Border Background="{StaticResource LightGray}" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource ReadOnlyTextBox}">
                <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding 
                    <!--ONLY THE FOLLOWING LINE IS DIFFERENT depends on property-->                 
                    Converter="{StaticResource PercentValueConverter}"
                    <!--Converter="{StaticResource FieldValueConverter}"-->
                    Mode="OneWay"
                    Path="DataContext.Item"
                    RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}"/>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
        </Border>

    </Grid>

</DataTemplate>
```

So I don't know how to specify particaular DataTemplate with correct converter via binding or any another way.
I have to do this in order to not repeat myself =)

Comment: Are you looking for template selector [check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx)